# Making an IF statement with a vlookup as a correct answer. Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to make an IF statement with a VLOOKUP as a true value however i am getting an error when i add the VLOOKUP.

The formula i am trying to use is:

```
=IF(G4="4B25",(VLOOKUP(I4,'Sheet2'!A41:D81,3,FALSE), " ")
```

The Error i am receiving is:

When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, excel thinks its a formula.

I am wanting to lookup a value in cell `I4` if Cell `G4` is 4B25. However if Cell `G4` is 2B25 then lookup cell `I4` but in a different table array.

Comment: `=IF(G4="4B25",(VLOOKUP(I4,'Sheet2'!A41:D81,3,FALSE)),"")` you have too many `," "`

Comment: NVM found my error. You fix this with the removal of the " "

Comment: I am wondering Scott can i run this twice? e.g: =IF(G4="4B25",(VLOOKUP(I4,'Sheet2'!A41:D81,3,FALSE), " "),(G4="2B25",(VLOOKUP(I4,'Sheet2'!G41:I81,3,FALSE), " ").

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment question:

```
=IF(G4="4B25",VLOOKUP(I4,'Sheet2'!A41:D81,3,FALSE),IF(G4="2B25",VLOOKUP(I4,'Sheet2'!G41:I81,3,FALSE), " "))
```